# converting three columns to unix time R

Tags: r, date

I have a dataset, where the dates are given in three columns: year, month, day. I want to convert this to the standard R date format (i.e. days since 1-1-1970). Right now I have this:

```
date <- as.Date(paste(year,month,day, sep="-"))
```

However I am wondering if this is the correct way / if there is a more efficient way.

Comment: Please post a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  Also, what do you mean by efficient?

Comment: My question is basically, is this the way you would expect this to be done, or is there a specific function / method for this.

Answer (score 6):

The `as.Date` function represents a date as the number of *days* since Jan 1, 1970. Unix time refers to the number of *seconds* since Jan 1, 1970. You'll want to use the `as.POSIXct` function and then convert it to a numeric object:

```
as.double(as.Date(paste(year, month, day, sep="-"))) # days since 1970-1-1
as.double(as.POSIXct(as.Date(paste(year, month, day, sep="-")))) # seconds since 1970-1-1
```

Comment: thank you, I guess Unix time was not the right term, just days since 1-1-1970 works.

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty much the standard way to do this. In fact, if you look at the code of `ISOdatetime` you can see that it uses a similar algorithm.